# How to check whether one date is bigger than the other?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to trace expire date of materials. To do so, I need to search for specific time interval (e.g. 80 days prior and 40 days later from today).

First, I set today's date in dd/mm/yyyy format. Then, take two input from user such that the first one is to identify the date after today (say x), and the second input for how many days before today (say y).

Now, I need to compare (today + x) and (today - y) dates with expiration date of materials such that whether shelf life of the materials fall within [y,x] interval. However, I am stuck.

I define rear and further as inputBox variables. Value entered to rear would be assigned to the variable x and give "rear" days prior today, and value entered to further would be assigned to variable y and take us "further" days after.

Here I identify today's date ("G1" cell) and time interval with x and y dates as well

```
Public Sub date()

Dim DateToProcess As Date

DateToProcess = Date

BUBD.Cells.Range("G1") = DateToProcess

rear = InputBox("How many days do you want to trace back?")
x = DateAdd("d", -rear, CDate(Range("G1")))


further = InputBox("How many days after do you want to check?")
y = DateAdd("d", further, CDate(Range("G1")))

End Sub
```

Then I want to compare materials BUBD with x and y

```
If rngRisk(j) > x Or rngRisk(j) < y
```

When I compare x and y with expire dates in rngRisk column, all values are pasted regardless of being in the interval

How can I compare expire dates of materials with x and y?

Comment: We do not see all of your code, but perhaps this could work.
`If CDate(rngRisk(j)) > x And CDate(rngRisk(j)) < y Then …. `

Comment: Could you provide your full if statement and some sample data?

Comment: You want `And` not `Or`

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your code is not being able to compare dates.

I will assume that rngRisk(j) is a Excel cell, in that case what might be happening is the type of the data in the cell is coming on the wrong format. If the cell is formated as Date, you could do rngRisk(j).Value2.  It should returns the date or the number of days since 1900 until the specified date.

OBS: x and y should be date or long type in order to compare dates

in case the cell is in date format

```
If rngRisk(j).Value2 > x
```

in case the cell is in text format

```
If CDate(rngRisk(j).Value2) > x
```

**Edit:**

Sample for compare dates

```
Sub CompareDates()

Dim rngDates As Range
Dim initialDate As Date
Dim finalDate As Date
Dim dateInColumn As Variant

initialDate = Date ' today
finalDate = Date + 3 ' 3 days from now

Set rngDates = ActiveSheet.Range("b2:b21") ' range with dates

For Each dateInColumn In rngDates

    If dateInColumn.Value2 > initialDate And dateInColumn.Value2 < finalDate Then

        MsgBox CDate(dateInColumn.Value2) & " is in between " & initialDate & " and " & finalDate

    End If

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Hello! rngRisk is an Excel column containing materials expire dates. I need to compare each value in that range with x and y, and write them in another column if dates are between x and y.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

Firstly, always use `Option Explicit` on the very top of your code before your `Subs`.
This will force you to declare your variables which will save you from errors that have to do with data types.

Second, x, y and rngRisk should be declared as `date` in order to be reliably compared to a date.

Finally, you can just add integers to a variable declared as date like so

```
dim tomorrow as date
tomorrow = Date + 1
```

Comment: Somewhat helpful, but now answering the OP's question. There should not be a question in your answer.

Comment: @MrDogme You are right. It was a rhetoric question really and I didn't expect an answer from the OP. However, I do get your point and I edited it out. Thank you for pointing this out.